# How can I remove null fields from CONCAT statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I am concatenating a few string fields using the CONCAT() function.  Here is the code:

```
CONCAT(a.[OrganizationalUnit], ' - ', a.[Level1], ' - ', a.[Level2], ' - ', a.[Level3], ' - ', a.[Level4], ' - ', a.[Level5], ' - ', a.[Level6], ' - ', a.[Level7], ' - ', a.[Level8], ' - ', a.[Level9], ' - ', a.[Level10], ' - ', a.[Level11], ' - ', a.[Level12], ' - ', a.[Level13], ' - ', a.[Level14]) AS Organization
```

There are some fields that are null.  When this happens, I receive a series of dashes in the output.  Is there a way I can get rid of those when the fields are blank?  Here is an example of output:

Company123 - Countries - LC BR - BR - RCL - 5510-RC BR (V) - EM - DG -  -  -  -  -  -  -

Comment: You can do some separate parsing of the output to remove trailing dashes if you wish. That should be done in the language calling SQL (for example, PHP)

Comment: I'd like to be able to do it in my query as I am using a front-end that really doesn't have that capability.

Comment: Um, what kind of a frontend do you have that can't do anything at all to the output of the SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Surround your fields with an if statement:

```
(IF (field not null) then field)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the SQL server version, so I would assume SQL Server 2012 or newer and use `iif` (instant if) which is available in SQL 2012 or newer. See more info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)

The solution below uses variables, just to show some executable code as an example. You can replace variables with your column names.

```
declare 
    @column1 varchar(10) = 'c1',
    @column2 varchar(10) =  null,
    @column3 varchar(10) = 'c3',
    @column4 varchar(10) = 'c4',
    @column5 varchar(10) = null,
    @column6 varchar(10) = null,
    @columnN varchar(10) = null -- 'cN'

declare @concatenated varchar(100) 

select @concatenated =  
    rtrim
    (
        concat 
        (
            iif(@column1  is not null, concat(@column1, ' - '), ''),
            iif(@column2  is not null, concat(@column2, ' - '), ''),
            iif(@column3  is not null, concat(@column3, ' - '), ''),
            iif(@column4  is not null, concat(@column4, ' - '), ''),
            iif(@column5  is not null, concat(@column5, ' - '), ''),
            iif(@column6  is not null, concat(@column6, ' - '), ''),
            @columnN
        )
    )

select rtrim(left(@concatenated, len(@concatenated) - patindex('%[^-]%', reverse(@concatenated))+1)) as 'Result'
```

This returns result as `c1 - c3 - c4`

The first `select` concatenates the values together.

The second `select` removes any trailing spaces and dashes caused by null fields concatenated towards the end.

The logic can handle scenarios like all values null, intermediate values null, last value null, last any values null.

Comment: What if the last field is null?

Comment: @tsqln00b good point. I modified the code to handle this and variations of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Just nest the `' - '+a.Leveln` within each concat part.

```
Declare @YourTable table ([OrganizationalUnit] varchar(10),Level1 varchar(10),Level2 varchar(10),Level3 varchar(10),Level4 varchar(10),Level5 varchar(10),Level6 varchar(10),Level7 varchar(10),Level8 varchar(10),Level9 varchar(10),Level10 varchar(10),Level11 varchar(10),Level12 varchar(10),Level13 varchar(10),Level14 varchar(10),Level15 varchar(10))
Insert Into @YourTable (OrganizationalUnit,Level1,Level2) values ('Org Unit','LevelOne','LevelTwo')

Select CONCAT(a.[OrganizationalUnit], ' - '+a.[Level1], ' - '+ a.[Level2], ' - '+ a.[Level3], ' - '+ a.[Level4], ' - '+ a.[Level5], ' - '+ a.[Level6], ' - '+ a.[Level7], ' - '+ a.[Level8], ' - '+ a.[Level9], ' - '+ a.[Level10], ' - '+ a.[Level11], ' - '+ a.[Level12], ' - '+ a.[Level13], ' - '+ a.[Level14]) 
From @YourTable A
```

Returns

```
Org Unit - LevelOne - LevelTwo
```